# Can no longer upload images to imgur from localhost

Tags: javascript, frontend, imgur

I have a react app where I upload images to imgur like:

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file);
  return fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/image/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    body: formData,
  })
```

I used to be able to upload images from my localhost, but now when I run the same code I get:

`Access to fetch at 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

So does this mean imgur updated their CORS policy?

Answer (score 1):

Imgur's API does not allow `localhost` for some reason, but it does allow other addresses. If you add an entry to `/etc/hosts` (unix) or with dnscmd (windows) that points to localhost, it will work fine from that address

```
127.0.0.1 imgurtesting
dnscmd /RecordAdd imgurtesting * 3600 A 127.0.0.1
```

The api will work from `http://imgurtesting:…/…` in your browser.